# How to add/sub to a dynamic variable?

Tags: css, less

I have a problem with the following code:

```
@viewport-large: 1440px;
@viewport-medium: 1366px;
@viewport-small: 1280px;

@type: medium;
@setting: ~"@{viewport-@{type}}";
@value: (@setting + 1); // here can't add 1
```

It will show an error message in the `LESS` compiler saying: "Operation on an invalid type".

Can anyone tell me why this is the case? What should I do?

Comment: Try `(@setting + 1px)` or `calc(@setting + 1px)`

Comment: Thanks but not works.

Comment: Thanks guys. the problem was solved.

Comment: @Harry thanks for the clarification, will retract the dupe flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of Less' [CSS escape function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e) (`e()` or `~""`) is  a ***string*** and you can't add a number to it. This is why the compiler reports ***Operation on invalid type***.

So, instead of doing it that way make use of the double resolution (`@@`) like in the below code block:

```
@viewport-large: 1440px;
@viewport-medium: 1366px;
@viewport-small: 1280px;

@type: medium;
@setting: "viewport-@{type}"; /* this won't resolve into 1336px as yet */
@value: @@setting + 1px; /* resolution to 1336px + addition happens here */
```

In this method, we just form the variable name and set it to the `@setting` variable (instead of setting a actual px value) and so the real px value's type remains ***unpolluted***. In the next line when we use the double `@`, Less compiler would try to fetch the value that is held by the variable whose name is same as the value of `@setting` variable and immediately sum 1px to it instead of converting it to a String.

**Note:** If you have the Strict Math option (`--strict-math`) enabled then the addition operation must be wrapped inside extra braces like below. Else, it would plainly output a concatenated value like *1366px + 1px* instead of performing the addition and outputting 1367px.

```
@value: (@@setting + 1px);
```

The `--strict-math` setting is disabled by default but some of your projects could have enabled it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is work! but "@value: @@setting + 1px" will output "1366px + 1px", I changed to "@value: (@@setting + 1px)" and then it output 1367px!!

Comment: @Jasper: That's probably because you have `strict-math` setting turned on. It is not mandatory otherwise and `strict-math` is by default off. I will anyway make a note of this in the answer.

Comment: I see, I will check the strict-math setting. thank you.